# initializing of constant variable using method (C#)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Is it possible to initializing value of a constant value using method of another class

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const int gravit = haha.habc();//something like this
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            some codes.....

        }
        public class haha
        {
            int gar = 1;
            public int habc()
            {
                int sa = 1;
                return sa;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

For example like the codes above(FYI with this code I am getting Expression being assigned to ... must be constant), if not is there other method to do something similar to this.

Comment: "constant variable" pretty much sums up the misunderstanding here ;-)

Answer (score 7):

No, that's not possible, you could use `readonly` field instead because constant values should be known at compile-time:

```
private static readonly int gravit = haha.habc();//something like this
```

NOTE: the `habc` method should be static if you want to call it that way.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - Is `Dependency Resolver` missing in the code line `private static readonly int gravit = haha.habc();` ?

Comment: value returned by this function `int A() => 1;` is known even before compile time.

Answer (score 1):

[Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173119%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) are values which should be known at compile time and do not change. So the [ReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is the option you should go with.

```
private readonly int gravit = haha.habc();
```