# why can't I define a non printable character as constant c#

Tags: c#

```
private const string requireNonPrintableChar = new string('\x0005', 1);
```

I do not expect this value to change. I was told once upon a time it's good practise to use const for values you don't expect to change.

However msbuild is saying:
"Error  1   The expression being assigned to requireNonPrintableChar' must be constant"

am assuming that char doesn't count as a const but why?

The msdn says it can be a string which I believe it is.

Comment: "msdn says it can be a string" - I believe that it should say it can be a string *literal*. Either it does and you're ignoring that second part or the documentation is in error. However, you've not linked to MSDN.

Comment: In my defence it does say string and not string literal https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx. 1st time the msdn has failed me but am by no means an experienced developer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A constant has to be defined directly. You can't use functions to get your const value.

Instead of doing this

```
const string MY_CONST = test();

        static string GetValue()
        {
            return "Hello";
        }
```

You should do this

```
const string MY_CONST = "Hello";
```

If you want to use method initialization you could use static readonly like this

```
private static readonly string requireNonPrintableChar = new string('\x0005', 1);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141516/initializing-of-constant-variable-using-method-c)

Answer (score 5):

Simply do:

```
private const string requireNonPrintableChar = "\x0005";
```

`new string('\x0005', 1)` is an expression that *does* get evaluated to a string, but it is not a compile-time constant, and `const` fields can only be assigned values which can be evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what w0lf said:

```
private const string requireNonPrintableChar = "\x0005";
```

But if you want your second paramter for cound, use:

```
private static readonly string requireNonPrintableChar = new string('\x0005', 1); // should be greater than 1
```